# schema registry mtls enabled

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, mtls

I have deployed k8s Deployment schema registry with:

```
image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.4.0
```

I setup spec.containers.env:

```
- name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME
  value: schema-registry
- name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
  value: ...
- name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS
  value: https://0.0.0.0:8081
- name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SECURITY_PROTOCOL
  value: SSL
- name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION
  value: ...
- name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
  value: ...
- name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION
  value: ...
- name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
  value: ...
- name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_INTER_INSTANCE_PROTOCOL
  value: https
```

...

I have deployed LoadBalancer also for schema registry

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations: 
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"
  name: schema-registry
  namespace: schema-registry
  labels:
    app: schema-registry
spec:
  selector:
    app: schema-registry
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081
  type: LoadBalancer
```

schema-registry to kafka over mtls authn seems to be OK.

Question:
How can I communicate with schema-registry over mtls to e.g. create schema using external access to schema-registry?

```
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [SSL://...:SOME_PORT]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = KafkaStore-reader-_schemas
    client.rack =
    confluent.proxy.protocol.client.address = null
    confluent.proxy.protocol.client.port = null
    confluent.proxy.protocol.client.version = NONE
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = schema-registry-schema-registry-8081
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor, class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 45000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = /mnt/secrets/user.jks
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = /mnt/secrets/truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
```